# How do I create a coloured text?

Tags: linux, d

In C++ the following code when run in the console will print the text in colour:

```
cout << "\e[32;40mGreenForegroundAndBlackBackgroundText" << endl;
```

In D I get an error:

```
string s = "\e[32;40mGreenForegroundAndBlackBackgroundText";  // undefined escape sequence \e
```

Is there any way to get this working in D?

Comment: Keep in mind that the escape sequences above won't work in any other non-ANSI terminal.

Comment: I have been working on [a library for this](http://code.google.com/p/decora)!  (I cannot believe how serendipitous this is.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ constant string escape `\e` for the escape character is a non-standard GCC extension of C for [character escapes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Character-Escapes.html#Character-Escapes) (also adopted by Clang, probably).

You just need to put the octal encoding of it perhaps as `\033` or `\x1b`

Be careful however that `\e[32;40m` is not standard C or C++, it is the ANSI terminal escape sequence related to [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php)-s.